# How to convert an image into another format using Imagick and display that in canvas?

Tags: php, javascript, imagemagick, imagick

I am using Imagick library to convert an image in TIFF format to PNG image. It works perfectly fine. But the real problem is I cannot render the image into html5 canvas. TIFF image contains multiple pages. I have a pagination on top of my web page. When I click on each, I want to convert corresponding page in TIFF to PNG and display it in canvas, which is not working. Any advice?

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot display your PNG on HTML5 canvas?

Comment: @Dennis-I can convert. But it is not working synchronously. I mean tiff to png conversion and then display on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/). If you have a php page that already returns the requested image then just change the contents of the Image.src property to point at that service with the file and page number in the parameter string.

Comment: I have a php page. Everything works fine on page load. My problem is when I take next page of the tiff, the conversion and display doesn't work synchronously.